# How to use minimax alalgorithm without recursion?

Tags: recursion, stack, minimax, structured-text

I'm developing a program that people can play "tic tac toe" with a computer.
I choose structured text as my develop language, but it doesn't have recursion, so I have to develop it without recursion.
As the result,  I decide to use the stack to instead, but I don't know how to change recursion into the stack.

I try to use stack like BFS, and also I wanna that minimax can make the best move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Structured Text, but maybe it helps to see a solution in another language.

You need a stack with moves, so that when backtracking, you know from where to start to search for a next, alternative move for it.

You also need a stack of scores, so you know the best score so far at every depth of the minimax search tree.

The two stacks could be combined into one stack when you can store the two data in one structure to be placed on the single stack. But in the below implementation in JavaScript I have tried to keep the data structures as simple as possible and used two stacks (fix-sized arrays with a separate size variable). All variables are declared at the top of the functions (as in Structured Text), and `return` statements are always at the end of the function bodies (since there is no `return` statement in Structured Text).

```js
function gameWon(board) {
    /* Looks at all possible lines of 3,
     * to see if they are occupied by three of the same symbols
     * board: is a 1D array with 9 integers: 
     * 1 = "X" (first player), 0 = free, 1 = "O"
     * Returns boolean.
     */
    let value;
    let i;
    // In Structured Text you'd not have gameWonReturn, 
    //    as you would use `gameWon` instead for returning a value
    let gameWonReturn = false; 
    
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        value = board[i*3];
        if (value != 0 && value == board[i*3+1] && value == board[i*3+2]) {
            gameWonReturn = true;
            break;
        }
        value = board[i];
        if (value != 0 && value == board[i+3] && value == board[i+6]) {
            gameWonReturn = true;
            break;
        }
        if (value != 0 && value == board[4] && value == board[8-i]) {
            gameWonReturn = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return gameWonReturn;
}

function play(board, moveStack, moveCount, move) {
    let playReturn;
    
    // Derive played symbol from number of moves played
    board[move] = 1 - (moveCount % 2) * 2; // Use MOD operator. Result is 1 or -1
    moveStack[moveCount] = move; // Log move in stack
    playReturn = moveCount + 1;
    return playReturn;
}

function minimax(board, moveStack, moveCount) {
    const scoreStack = Array(10); // Array of signed integers
    const originalMoveCount = moveCount;
    let move;          // -1..9
    let score;         // -10..10
    let player;        // -1 or 1
    let minimaxReturn = -1; // -1..9

    while (true) {
        // Current player can be derived from the number of moves that were played
        player = 1 - (moveCount % 2) * 2; // 1 = First, maximizing player. -1 = Second, minimizing player
        // Check for game-over
        if (gameWon(board)) { // Preceding move resulted in win for previous player
            scoreStack[moveCount] = -(10 - moveCount) * player; // Earlier wins get greater score
        } else if (moveCount == 9) { // It's a draw
            scoreStack[moveCount] = 0;
        } else {
            moveStack[moveCount] = -1; // Prepare for iterating moves for current player
            scoreStack[moveCount] = -player * 10; // Initialize with worst possible score for current player
            moveCount++;
        }
        do { // Repeat:
            moveCount--;
            if (moveCount < originalMoveCount) { // All done
                break; // Exit point
            }
            // Look for a next, valid move
            move = moveStack[moveCount];
            if (move >= 0) { // Was a valid move: derive score from deeper results
                score = scoreStack[moveCount + 1]; // Best score opponent can get
                if ((board[move] == 1) == (score > scoreStack[moveCount])) { // Improvement
                    scoreStack[moveCount] = score;
                    if (moveCount == originalMoveCount) {
                        minimaxReturn = move; // For now this is a best move...
                    }
                }
                // Take back move
                board[move] = 0;
            }
            // Look for next valid move
            do {
                move++;
            } while (move < 9 && board[move] != 0) // Occupied
        } while (move == 9); // Backtrack (i.e. repeat loop) when all moves were tried

        if (moveCount < originalMoveCount) { // All done
            break; // Exit point
        }
        // Play move
        moveCount = play(board, moveStack, moveCount, move);
    }
    return minimaxReturn;
}

function main() {
    const board = Array(9).fill(0); // An empty 3x3 board as 1 dimensional array
    const moveStack = Array(10);    // History of played moves (indices in board)
    let moveCount = 0;              // Number of moves played
    let bestMove;
    
    /* Demo:
     * Play moves to arrive at this board:
     *  
     *     X | O | 
     *    ---+---+---
     *     O |   |
     *    ---+---+---
     *     X |   |
     */     
    moveCount = play(board, moveStack, moveCount, 0); // Play X in top-left
        moveCount = play(board, moveStack, moveCount, 1); // Play O next to it
    moveCount = play(board, moveStack, moveCount, 6); // Play X in bottom-left
        moveCount = play(board, moveStack, moveCount, 3); // Play O in middle row
    
    // Run minimax for suggesting where to play an "X":
    bestMove = minimax(board, moveStack, moveCount);
    console.log(bestMove); // 4 (center of the board)
}
main();
```